# How to use ref inside stateless ScrollViewRTL component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ref, stateless

Actually, I wanna make a general purpose `ScrollViewRTL` component for my `react-native` project. The main target I wanna work on it is the **RTL** situation of the ScrollView component. But the ScrollView component with any property doesn't show an RTL situation, please pay attention to the below codes:

```
import React, { memo } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { StyleSheet, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { variables } from 'utils/constants/theme';
import { styleJoiner } from 'utils/helpers';

const ScrollViewRTL = ({ children, style, contentContainerStyle, ...rest }) => (
  <ScrollView
    {...rest}
    style={styleJoiner(styles.wrapper, style)}
    horizontal
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    contentContainerStyle={styleJoiner(
      styles.contentContainer,
      contentContainerStyle
    )}
  >
    {children}
  </ScrollView>
);

ScrollViewRTL.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.element,
    PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.element),
    PropTypes.func
  ]).isRequired,
  style: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.object, PropTypes.array]),
  contentContainerStyle: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.object,
    PropTypes.array
  ])
};

ScrollViewRTL.defaultProps = {
  style: undefined,
  contentContainerStyle: undefined
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  contentContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row-reverse',
    minWidth: '100%',
    paddingHorizontal: variables.gutter
  },
  wrapper: {
    flexGrow: 0
  }
});

export default memo(ScrollViewRTL);
```

But it stands at the start of the LTR situation, for the below example I set 30 texts that began from zero to 29, you can see it is at the end of the RTL that it means it is at the start of the LTR situation:

[image]

So I decide to scroll it to the end of LTR situation that seems it is at the start of RTL situation, But I don't wanna use Component or PureComponent just for using `ref`, I wanna use `ref` in the above stateless component, *How I can do it?*

Comment: I don't understand exactly what's the problem, but if your problem is only with ref, you can use ref inside Component or PureComponent also.

Comment: Dear @SiSa, Thanks for your answer. But I know there is some way to use `ref` inside the stateless component.